# I'm having an error running a remote CD command over a TCP socket

Tags: python, sockets

So, here's my issue. I'm running a database-ish thing for some roleplaying stuff (don't mind that part) and I'm trying to get a `cd` function to work (using `os.chdir(f"{path}")`, where `path` is the received/decoded message). You connect using port forwarding to protect IP addrs, and you type `cd`, it prompts with `"to which folder"` then you type the folder (there's also an `ls` command).

I keep getting an error when I try to change the path to what was entered on the client side:

> stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not set

Here's the code for the server:

**Server.py**

```py
import os
import socket
from os import name as os_name, system
from colorama import init, Fore as cc
import select
import threading
import time
from discord import SyncWebhook

dr = DR = r = R = cc.LIGHTRED_EX
g = G = cc.LIGHTGREEN_EX
b = B = cc.LIGHTBLUE_EX
m = M = cc.LIGHTMAGENTA_EX
c = C = cc.LIGHTCYAN_EX
y = Y = cc.LIGHTYELLOW_EX
w = W = cc.RESET
from pyngrok import ngrok
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = os.environ.get(f"socket.gethostname()")
port = 5050
FORMAT = "utf-8"
HEADER = 64
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!disconnect"
# Create a TCP socket
clear = lambda: system('cls') if os_name == 'nt' else system('clear')
# Bind a local socket to the port
server_address = ("", port)
server.bind(server_address)
server.listen(1)
# Open a ngrok tunnel to the socket
public_url = ngrok.connect(port, "tcp", options={"remote_addr": "{}:{}".format(host, port)})
clear()
print("Ngrok Tunnel \"{}\" -> \"tcp://127.0.0.1:{}/\"".format(public_url, port))
webhook = SyncWebhook.from_url("https://discord.com/apl/webhooks/954023084753584138/RFewgv20GIYjD9J2_Olm1gyEzVAcmFSNCb0IaAXcdcM1WL3xtDEUNApeLTsa8QZMb")
webhook.send(f"{public_url}")
def handle_client(conn, addr):
    connected = True
    while connected:
        try:
            msg_length = conn.recv(HEADER).decode(FORMAT)
            if msg_length:
                msg_length = int(msg_length)
                msg = conn.recv(msg_length).decode(FORMAT)
                if msg == "SSH-2.0-ssh2js1.4.0\r\n":
                    connection.close()
                if msg == DISCONNECT_MESSAGE:
                    connected = False
                    print(f"[Connection {threading.activeCount() -1}] Disconnected")
                    conn.close()
                    return
                if msg == "pwd":
                    conn.send(f"{os.getcwd()}".encode(FORMAT))
                    handle_client(conn, addr)
                if msg == "ls":
                    conn.send(f"{os.listdir()}".encode(FORMAT))
                    handle_client(conn, addr)
                if msg == "cd":
                    conn.send(f"To which folder ? ".encode(FORMAT))
                    path = str(conn.recv(2048).decode(FORMAT))
                    if path == f"{os.path.isdir({path})}":
                        os.chdir(f"{path}")
                        conn.send(f"Changed Directory to {os.getcwd}").encode(FORMAT)
                        handle_client(conn, addr)
                    if not path == f"{os.path.isdir({messg})}":
                        conn.send(f"Unable to change directory to {messg}, it either doesnt exist or are lacking permissions!").encode(FORMAT)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            
    conn.close()     
def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening")
    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(conn, addr))
        thread.start()
    
print("[STARTING] Server is Starting...")
start()

sock.close()
```

I know its a lot to look over, but can someone please advise me on the error?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem with this line:

```py
                    if path == f"{os.path.isdir({path})}":
```

There's no need for the `{...}` around the second occurrence of `path` in this line, as you are already within braces with an `f`-string. In fact, this is the root of your `set` error: `{path}` is a 1-element set containing `path`, so you are passing a set to `os.path.isdir`, not a pathname.

Remove the braces immediately around `path`:

```py
                    if path == f"{os.path.isdir(path)}":
```

The same problem exists on the line

```py
                    if not path == f"{os.path.isdir({messg})}":
```

further down. However, as well as using unnecessary braces, you are also using a variable that hasn't been defined anywhere: `messg`. I'm guessing you probably want to use `path` instead. If that's the case, then you can in fact replace this line with

```py
                    else:
```

as the condition is just the opposite of the one in the previous `if` statement.  `messg` appears on the line below too, so you probably want to change that to `path` as well.

However, even having done this, it is unlikely that your code will do what you are expecting it to.  `os.path.isdir(path)` returns `True` if `path` is a directory, and `False` if not, so the condition `path == f"{os.path.isdir(path)}"` is only ever satisfied if `path` is a directory named `True` or a file named `False`, because you are comparing `path` to the result of converting `os.path.isdir(path)` to a string.

Did you perhaps want to check whether `path` was a directory? If so, the following would do that:

```py
                    if os.path.isdir(path):
```